# (Google scripts App)How can I run the script in the function before the user sees the sheets themselves

Tags: google-sheets-api

Due to the time delay from opening the sheet to the triggering of the script that hides the secret sheets, the user still sees them at first. How can I make the script execute in the onOpen () function before showing the main (not hidden) sheets.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your situation? Why hide a sheet `onOpen` and not having it hidden all the time?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11s9ueT9dN7RTxeVpx-5JqEApziKL13DuUNPA5Jy9Jn4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if you click on the star shape on sheet 1, a secret sheet will appear. But if you refresh the page (that is, do itOpen (), the secret list will not disappear instantly., There will be a delay and users will still see

Comment: function hideSheet() // activated in onOpen()
{
 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var sheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("secret sheet").hideSheet(); 
}

function showHidenSheet() //activated if you press on star shape on sheet1
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("secret sheet").showSheet();
}

function onOpen()
{
 hideSheet();
}

Comment: in function onOpen() of couse

Comment: So you want to hide a sheet when the spreadsheet is opened, but you want this to be faster than with an `onOpen` trigger. I don't think that's possible.